# My jquery is overwritting when appending to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I'm taking this HTML snippet below and I want to loop through a count then append each image HTML element into a div, but looping through the code below only the last item is getting appended. I think it's overwriting it or something or maybe the copying of the element isn't working the way I thought.

```js
var $container = $('#facebook-body-container');
$container.empty();

var $albumImage = $(".facebook-image");

for (var i = 0; i < response.albums.data.length; i++) {
  var tempImage = $albumImage;
  $(tempImage).find(".thumbnail").attr("id", response.albums.data[i].id);
  $(tempImage).find("img").attr("src", response.albums.data[i].picture.data.url);
  $(tempImage).find(".album-title").text(response.albums.data[i].name);
  $(tempImage).find(".album-photo-count").text(response.albums.data[i].photo_count);
  $container.append(tempImage);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageThumbnailContainer" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-sm-4 facebook-image">
    <div id="" class="thumbnail" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h4 class="album-title"></h4>
        <p class="album-photo-count"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are referring to same object, Use `clone()` i.e. `var tempImage = $albumImage.clone();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone the element first before changing the attributes using **[`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)** method, else the `$albumImage` will refer to the same instance :

```
var tempImage = $albumImage.clone(true);
```

The boolean `true` passed as a parameter indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements or not.